# How to get Scrapy Version 0.12?

Tags: python, download, version, scrapy

Scrapy does not seem to allow installing previous version.

The methods listed are:

```
easy_install -U Scrapy
```

and:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

Both these ways just download the latest versions of Scrapy, which i do not want. How do i get scrapy to download version 0.12?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install it manually:

```
vic@wic:~$ git clone git://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git
Cloning into 'scrapy'...
remote: Counting objects: 24639, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15949/15949), done.
remote: Total 24639 (delta 8402), reused 24317 (delta 8158)
Receiving objects: 100% (24639/24639), 10.73 MiB | 639 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8402/8402), done.

vic@wic:~$ cd scrapy/

vic@wic:~/scrapy$ git tag
0.10
0.10-rc1
0.10.1
0.10.2
0.10.3
0.14.0
0.14.1
0.14.2
0.14.3
0.14.4
0.7
0.7-rc1
0.8
0.9
0.9-rc1

vic@wic:~/scrapy$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/0.12
  remotes/origin/0.14                                                                                                                                               
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master                                                                                                                              
  remotes/origin/master                                                                                                                                             
  remotes/origin/singleton_removal                                                                                                                                  

vic@wic:~/scrapy$ git checkout 0.12                                                                                                                                 
Branch 0.12 set up to track remote branch 0.12 from origin.
Switched to a new branch '0.12'

vic@wic:~/scrapy$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old forum. But i also get stumble into this problem and found the solution which is more simple

You can use

```
pip install scrapy==1.1
```

Just change the 1.1 to the version you want
I wonder why they didn't place it in documentation because i have a hard time found it